# Trying to pull out dates and version numbers from script comments, using regex

Tags: python, regex, input

I'm trying to pull out information from comments in script files. After taking the file as input, I want to run a search that will pull out information in the form of:

"Version: #.#"

"Date Created: ##/##/####"

etc.

One of my problems is that the version numbers and dates wont always be in that format. Sometimes, they may look like:

"Version #"

"Date Created: ##/####"

The comments are generally filled with tons of "#'s' so what my regex looks like so far is:
**[\s\S]*(Version:?\s\d.?\d|Date Created:? \d+/\d+/\d{2,4}?)**

I'm trying to make it more robust in order to handle different scenarios (like the one I wrote above) and the *main problem* I want to solve is: **it is only pulling either the date or the version, I know this is due to the pipe (|), and because I don't know regex that well, I'm not sure how to grab both of those pieces of information.**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's because the pipe `|` operator means `This OR That`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think it is easier to break your regex's into multiple regex (i.e., one for versions, another for dates)
2. You should use anchors `^regex$` so that you find a full line in question. This makes your regex generally faster but definitely more specific.

Example:

```
import re

txt='''\
# Version: #.#"

# Date Created: ##/##/####"

etc.

One of my problems is that the version numbers and dates wont always be in that format. Sometimes, they may look like:

# Version #"

# Date Created: ##/####'''

print 'versions found:', re.findall(r'^\s*#+\s*Version:?\s*(.*)$', txt, re.M)    
print 'dates found:', re.findall(r'^\s*#+\s* Date Created:?\s*(.*)$', txt, re.M)
```

Prints:

```
versions found: ['#.#"', '#"']
dates found: ['##/##/####"', '##/####']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And I guess that splitting the regex is the best way to go, thanks again for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex,

```
Version:?\s*\S*|Date Created:?\s*\S*
```